# DDoS attack on SMTP

Tags: linux, email, smtp, cpanel, denial-of-service

I am not sure whether this is the right place to ask this. But now I am in a great difficult situation. Our server is undergoing SMTP DDoS attack. The mail service has been totally down.
We have checked with the datacenter team and they updated us to purchase a new firewall module, which I cant afford now. When we try to change the Port the attack can be stopped but the mail service goes down. Is there any possible way to stop this attack ?

```
OS: CentOS 
Mail service : exim 
SMTP port used : 25
```

Current mail log is shown as below:

```
2013-10-16 00:35:10 SMTP syntax error in "\223\032\020F\324\247\315f\200]\236m2\025\305sL\313\300y\377}\306\177]\246V\204\272n3\2115\031\335\215\240\247[\222\340*\340\230]\263\221\235\323=n\242\315\\260\2473\021q\255o\232a\263\262\306\016\2705A\261\2744\230`\302r\361\343=\376     \260\315\356-s\322\236C\255\327\353;\253\334h\304\207\341\276\201\324^\207\231\212\354\273"L\362:zNn\205\362\253r\240\032\235x\027u\211\006`\377\224\vR\204\360\020\265@k\025\301Y\212\033\204\346j!?9\026&\206)\215*:LP/[\006\3704\263W\206:P\340<@\360f\276D\365\3544I6\334\017O\242\377gT\277O\340Y\003B\330]\205\3103cj\201\333h\247|\264n]\366Bsr\260\352xXmH~\031]\210\203OG\351\207O&T\216b\276\273\221\fkY\230}\007G\024\271\351'\2422\r\367\246\366\352^#\203\b ):        \244\266\311\272\304\273\221\344\016\301|\236R\305\027\354]\314\266\246\206\321,5\313\325\305X?\333Mx\377\337me\304\346\205\341\230\352@<\217\357:\277\003\365\\370\331o\251\017\005\377V\365\004\005\275\200\324\200\231\241\026\206\260^N\023\304IB\031\020\230j\036\277\270\254#R\323!\250\2037h,\262^]>\371\3437DQ\374qI\355\362oNr?wSV\234\216X\244\212\204]\213lpc\302\264\252\334O\274\354\341C\333@r'\224\350w\306\254"}\220=\007\202\336+\375\206\351\r\351\214l\270\273\006" H=[181.67.204.178]:36043 I=[64.31.38.66]:25 NULL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2013-10-16 00:35:10 SMTP syntax error in "Q\356\226J\226\244\021y\033;\027\320W$\246\244\b\304\253\3444\020\260o#\006\265A6\275\273DF%7\201\205\265;4\246\016\312\244{"E\277P\312<\266\374\312\332\\272\365\336@\031\216\343\211 \005\350\304\352o\356\rkl\363\261%\225\370\344\262O\376\327z\003\002a\257\~\026(\266\204+\333H\022\307\3006\027\361S\234\033L5\007"\372,)\235\377kWJ\314\242\3270\216\334\203\254\364\223\233\262I5R\270\273W,F\365\341\211J?\322?O\241\345\267U\036n\224Z\373b\021`L\2478e\3549vi,\027\177\346\376Xa\3547\277\235\360$\213[\366\300\250\310\002\314s\274\b\2423\374\004H\341u\223\253\235\037\230\203\360\255\235u\017o\243\fd~\250\211\354Z\255\371\016\036\262\252/`\267[P\242\274\374\330~\301\227_\332\306\354\265j\313\353:E\321MZ\006\327fH\374\333\343\320\330\340\253\020v\Rd\004b\335fl\360@#\026\365\372\227\b\373\322\260\321u\037\215t\204\032\033d\202\232"\361\017Y\201\211\024>hw\031\327\233\312\225\215\246\336#\263\323\306(\243C/\245\344\017r\251\373\034\232\257t\265 \266\302FFB\264e\007H\326#l\303\374\332XRyc5WQV\301\334\232\246:a\027/\027f\026\264\361k\233\373urs\201Tz\325=\376~\2437\375\372\020\245(\212\016\322\020\217\304n\335\vy\226    \020R\356\373\241[J\023\247Li\324\254\210\3631\261=\243P\267\320h\2752\351\271\220\301\244t\272\306Xa.\314\241Q\245\3208\246\264\3257+\217\333\232\3478\340" H=[181.67.204.178]:36043 I=[64.31.38.66]:25 NULL character(s) present (shown as '?')
2013-10-16 00:35:10 SMTP syntax error in "" H=[181.67.204.178]:36043 I=[64.31.38.66]:25 unrecognized command
```

Again my sincere apologies if this is not the right place to ask this.

Regards,
Arun Kurian

Comment: How is the attack hurting you? Be as precise as possible. Is it maxing out your inbound bandwidth? Your outbound bandwidth? Your CPU? Or what?

Comment: How have you established that there is a DDoS taking place?

Comment: Paul has a good point. Are you 100% certain that it is in fact a DDoS attack and you aren't just using that term to mean any flood that affects service? Because the techniques for dealing with a DDoS attack are different from the techniques for handling other types of flooding attacks.

Comment: Checking the mail log (/var/log/exim_mainlog) we could see attempts for establishing connection from different IP's and different nations. This is been ongoing for the last couple of days

Comment: Your ISP should be able to help, contact them

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the output above, this seems more or less the same botnet that is attacking one of our servers too ... our logs showed something just shy of 30k unique IPs, with junk binary data sent from the moment the TCP session is up ... in such a situation, greylisting doesn't help any, as the problem is caused by the concurrent connections (at one point we counted around 2000 active/wait connections in the netstat output), which either runs the MTA into its process limit, or kills the CPU (if the limit of MTA processes is high enough).
For now we activated a firewall policy to block any incoming SMTP that's not originated from our networks (/16, /19), hoping those f@cking script kiddies will lose interest soon and stop the bot attack. What we'd have to set up here is some sort of low-impact transparent tool that takes care of the TCP handshake, check's for a valid connection, in which case it spoofs the handshake and initial data and lets the rest of the session flow through without any interaction ...
Yes, I know there are commercial solutions that do that, but they are well in the 5-digit range ...

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to advise without a lot more knowledge about what is going on (ie traffic details and server profile), and even then, this is probably not the correct forum to ask - Serverfault may be better ?

**Farm the problem out !!**

Depending on your profile, you might want to look at "farming the problem out".  By this I mean get another mail provider to handle your incoming email and forward it on to you.  Only allow connections from that mail provider and your internal IP addresses.  A search for "smtp mail filter services" will probably provide some candidate providers, or your upstrema provider might offer this service.

**General "do it yourself" solutions:**

If you are certain its (highly) distributed, try enabling [greylisting](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Spam-Filtering-for-MX/exim-greylisting.html).  This could help quite a bit depending on the nature of the attack.

If the problem is coming from a number of servers (but is not extremely distributed), look at using fail2ban and writing some custom rules.  I found that does wonders on distributed attacks on my wordpress sites.

Probably not an option, but it might be.  You might be able to use iptables to block geographic regions - for example if your customers are not in Russia or China, you could block incoming SMTP requests from these ranges using geolocation.  Of-course, this will stop legitimate traffic as well - it might not be an issue in a corporate environment with a targeted market though.